# How to use NSDate and NSString in a NSPredicate to fetch data from Core Data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsdate, nspredicate

I am facing a problem when I am fetching data from Core data database in my iPhone application.

I am using this code **(Line 1)** which is working fine, here I am fetching data from a date:

**Note:** Datatype of `date` is `NSDate` and `selectedDate` is also type of `NSDate`.

**Line1:**

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date == %@",selectedDate];
```

This code **(Line 2)** is also working fine When I am fetching data of a system:

**Line 2:**

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"systemName == '%@'",selectedSystemString]];
```

But when I combined the above two predicates with this code **(Line 3)**:

**Line 3:**

```
 [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"(date == %@) AND (systemName == '%@')",selectedDate,selectedSystemString]];
```

And application crashed on **Line 3**, and this error message is displayed in console:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "(date == 2015-01-15 18:30:00 +0000) AND (systemName == 'A')"'

*** First throw call stack:
(0x26494c1f 0x33c9cc8b 0x270feb55 0x270fc9bd 0x270fc93d 0x9b263 0x9c143 0xa8815 0x29a69f97 0x29b1bc0f 0x299cdc4d 0x29949aab 0x2645b3b5 0x26458a73 0x26458e7b 0x263a7211 0x263a7023 0x2d75a0a9 0x299b31d1 0xb1e7d 0x3421caaf)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Use `(systemName == %@)`

Comment: Thanks for comment @flexaddicted. I have used this code (systemName == %@) But Still crashing. :(

Comment: Do you receive the same error?

Comment: Yes, *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "(date == 2015-01-15 18:30:00 +0000) AND (systemName == A)"'

Comment: Are you using this one? `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date == %@ AND systemName == %@",selectedDate,selectedSystemString];`

Comment: I am using this code : [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"(date == %@) AND (systemName == %@)",selectedDateString,selectedSystemString]];

Comment: Ok. Spot the error. You don't need `NSString`.

Comment: I got my answer, and resolved this issue by below answer . Thanks to you too. :) (y)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between your first two lines is why the third one fails. (The second one is also incorrect but works because you're using strings.)

It's like using query parameters if you're familiar with SQL.

In line 1 you say, here's what I'm looking for with this parameter (which happens to be a date).

In line 2 you say, here's what I'm looking for. There are no parameters. It *should* be like this:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"systemName == %@",selectedSystemString];
```

Line 3 fails because you convert the date into a string (which uses the `description` method on `NSDate`); your predicate has no parameters. It should look more like this:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(date == %@) AND (systemName == %@)",selectedDate,selectedSystemString];
```

Comment: Thanks, Now I got actual reason of this issue. Thank you so much for this detail of issue :) _/\_ (y)

Answer (score 3):

try using compound predicate,

```
NSPredicate *datePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date == %@",selectedDate];
NSPredicate *stringPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"systemName == %@",selectedSystemString];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates: @[datePredicate, stringPredicate]];
```

compound predicate using `andPredicateWithSubpredicates:` method is similar to `AND` predicate, the solution using AND would be

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date == %@ AND systemName == %@",selectedDate, selectedSystemString];
```

Comment: `andPredicateWithSubpredicates` and `AND` are exactly the same.

Comment: Yes I just suggested the different approach, As per the @Stephen Darlington the real problem was [NSString stringWithFormat: ] which was converting the date predicate into string. I edited my answer with both solutions

Comment: Could you edit your anwer explaining that the two approaches are the the same? I will remove my downvote. Thanks.